# How to use OPENJSON in sql

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I am trying to use OpenJSON at JSON data but it is not producing the result as expected. DB JSON in field_data is:

```
{  
    "name":"Test",
    "Cell-Number":"Test",
    "CNIC":"12112112",
    "Person-Name":"Test",
    "Focal-person-cell-phone":"121212",
    "Focal-person-CNIC":"12121212",
    "Religion":"Test",
    "Total-teachers":"4",
    "Total-students":"37",
    "Total-Hosteled-students":"11",
    "Government-\/-Private":"Govt",
    "Category":"Jamia",
    "Total-Gates":"3",
    "Registration-number":"211121",
    "Security-guard\/watchman":"10",
    "Condition":"Test"
}
```

I am trying to fetch the data where name is equal to Test in field_data column.
My Query to fetch data is ;

```
SELECT *
FROM beat_data 
WHERE EXISTS (
  Select *
  FROM OPENJSON(field_data,'$.name') 
  WHERE Value = 'Test'
)
```

I have feelings that I am not using the path properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try to use `JSON_VALUE()`:

Input:

```
CREATE TABLE #BeatData (
   JsonColumn nvarchar(max)
)
INSERT INTO #BeatData
   (JsonColumn)
VALUES
   (N'{  
    "name":"Test",
    "Cell-Number":"Test",
    "CNIC":"12112112",
    "Person-Name":"Test",
    "Focal-person-cell-phone":"121212",
    "Focal-person-CNIC":"12121212",
    "Religion":"Test",
    "Total-teachers":"4",
    "Total-students":"37",
    "Total-Hosteled-students":"11",
    "Government-\/-Private":"Govt",
    "Category":"Jamia",
    "Total-Gates":"3",
    "Registration-number":"211121",
    "Security-guard\/watchman":"10",
    "Condition":"Test"
}')
```

T-SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM #BeatData
WHERE JSON_VALUE(JsonColumn, '$.name') = N'Test'
```

If you want to get `JSON` data as result set, try with the following:

```
SELECT j.*
FROM #BeatData b
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(b.JsonColumn) WITH (
    name varchar(100) '$.name',
    [Cell-Number] varchar(100) '$."Cell-Number"',
    CNIC varchar(100) '$.CNIC',
    [Person-Name] varchar(100) '$."Person-Name"',
    [Focal-person-cell-phone] varchar(100) '$."Focal-person-cell-phone"',
    [Focal-person-CNIC] varchar(100) '$."Focal-person-CNIC"',
    Religion varchar(100) '$.Religion',
    [Total-teachers] varchar(100) '$."Total-teachers"',
    [Total-students] varchar(100) '$."Total-students"',
    [Total-Hosteled-students] varchar(100) '$."Total-Hosteled-students"',
    [Government-\/-Private] varchar(100) '$."Government-\/-Private"',
    Category varchar(100) '$.Category',
    [Total-Gates] varchar(100) '$."Total-Gates"',
    [Registration-number] varchar(100) '$."Registration-number"',
    [Security-guard\/watchman] varchar(100) '$."Security-guard\/watchman"',
    Condition varchar(100) '$.Condition'
) j
WHERE j.name = N'Test'
```

Comment: Hello @Zhorov, above query producing 0 result.. look like where condition is not working properly.

Comment: Point to be noted.. i dont have any N in my JSON.

Comment: @Nadeem `'N'` denotes that the subsequent string is in unicode. Try to execute statements without `WHERE` to see actual results.

Comment: Do i need to add it while inserting JSON data ?

Comment: Its showing data without where class.. but nothing with where class.

Comment: ok , i insert data with N  now where condition is working fine... can i use it without inserting N, as in that way maybe i have to change it in many places while inserting or it is necessary ?

Comment: @Nadeem `OPENJSON()` expects unicode character expression containing valid `JSON` text as first parameter. Or use explicit `CONVERT(nvarchar(max), ...)`. Thanks.

Comment: can you please explain your last statement ?

Comment: @Nadeem You need to use `N` when inserting data, to be sure that your column data is unicode, or use `CONVERT(nvarchar(max), ...)` when inserting.